# UICollectionViewCell dynamic sizing for 4.4 and 5.5 inch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I have UICollectionView with cells in the storyboard. The size of each cell is set to 145x145.

They look good on the iPhone 4 - 5s, but the size doesn't increase proportionally on the iPhone 6 and 6+. Rather than manually setting a different cell size for each device, how can I do it dynamically?

See examples here: iPhone 5S: http://prntscr.com/55vy7q, iPhone 6: http://prntscr.com/55vyy2

Comment: you can use `-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
` delegate method for cell size.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want your cells to adjust their width, you'll need to calculate the flow layout's `itemSize` based on the view width.

- **If all your cells will be the same size**, you can set the flow layout's `itemSize` property:

  ```
  #define kCellsPerRow 2

  UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
  CGFloat availableWidthForCells = CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionView.frame) - flowLayout.sectionInset.left - flowLayout.sectionInset.right - flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * (kCellsPerRow - 1);
  CGFloat cellWidth = availableWidthForCells / kCellsPerRow;
  flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, flowLayout.itemSize.height);
  ```

  *If you want to dynamically vary the number of cells per row, I've provided those [details in a separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36315107/4151918).*
- **If you need to calculate per-cell sizes**, you can do it in the `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` delegate.

Recalculate the itemSize when the device orientation changes and update the layout:

- **Redraw layout without animation:**

  `[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout]`
- **Animate layout changes:**

  `[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:nil]`

Comment: I'd like to thank the original poster for raising the question and you for answering it. I've come so close yet I am still stuck on the last part. I've posted my question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36312979/dynamic-cell-width-in-respect-to-frame-width-aspect-ratio)

Comment: @user4151918 in what method would you set the collectionviewflowlayout?